# Three.js LatheGeometry won't cast shadows

Tags: three.js, geometry, shadow

Lathe Geometry won't cast shadows but spheres and cubes do. Why is that ?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVmsf.jpg)

My renderer:

```
var webGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    webGLRenderer.setClearColor(0xAAAAAA, 1.0);
    webGLRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    webGLRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
```

Lathe:

```
 var latheGeometry = new THREE.LatheGeometry(array, Math.ceil(segments), 0, 2 * Math.PI);

        //var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00, transparent:true, opacity:0.6});
var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFFFFFF});
meshMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
var wireFrameMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
wireFrameMat.wireframe = false;

latheMesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(latheGeometry,[meshMaterial, wireFrameMat]);
latheMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -0.5;
        latheMesh.position.z = 0;
    latheMesh.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(latheMesh);
```

My lighting:

```
var pointColor = "#ffffff";
    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(pointColor);
    directionalLight.position.set(-50,50,50);
    directionalLight.castShadow = true;
    directionalLight.receiveShadow = false;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;

    directionalLight.intensity = 1;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraNear = 50;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraFar = 200;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraLeft = -50;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraRight = 40;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraTop = 50;
    directionalLight.shadowCameraBottom = -50;


    directionalLight.distance = 0;
    directionalLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
    directionalLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;

    //scene.add( new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(directionalLight, 0.5) );
    scene.add(directionalLight);
```

As you can see, only sphere can cast shadow and not latheGeometry.

Answer (score 2):

`THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject()` creates a `THREE.Group` with a child `Mesh` for each material.

You need to specify the `castShadow` property not for the group, but for the child mesh you want to cast the shadow.

three.js r.76